# Angular Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | undefined'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to remove the task in my child component by using function from parent component but unable to do this as its given the error here my code in app.component.html

```
<input #taskList type="text" placeholder="To Do List">
<button (click)='addTaskList(taskList.value); taskList.value = ""' (removedTaskEvent)="removedTask($event)">Add Task</button>

<ul *ngFor="let task of list">
    <app-child [item]="task"></app-child>
</ul>
```

and the function i am using in my app.ts

```
list: any[] = [];
  addTaskList(item: any) {
    console.log(item)
    this.list.push({ id: this.list.length, name: item })
  }

  removedTask(id: string) {
    console.log(id);
    this.list = this.list.filter(item => item.id !== id)
  }
```

my child component.html code is as per below

```
<li>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>{{item.id}}</td>
            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
            <td><button (click)="removedTaskEvent.emit(item.id)"> x </button></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</li>
```

and child.component.ts is following

```
@Input() item: {id:number, name: string} = {id:0, name:""};
@Output() removedTaskEvent = new EventEmitter<string>();
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are emitting the **removedTaskEvent** , you are emitting "item.id" through it, which is a number, as defined in the ts.
But the removedTask(id: string) method accepts a string parameter.
Change the parameter type to number or any to solve the issue.